# 2D graph in Scilab

Tags: math, graph, scilab

I have to make a 2D graph in Scilab, and I'm not sure if the code I wrote is correct.

This problem aims for 2-D plot.

Plot the function `y = x2 − 2` in the interval `[-5, 5]`

I have to graph this equation in Scilab and I'm not sure if the way y wrote it is correct or not.

```
--> x = -5 : 5;
--> y = x^2 - 2
```

**Warning:** Syntax *"vector ^ scalar"* is obsolete. It will be removed in Scilab 6.0. Use *"vector .^ scalar"* instead.

```
y =

23.    14.    7.    2.  - 1.  - 2.  - 1.    2.    7.    14.    23.  

--> plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only weak point in your code is
y=x^2-2  instead of y=x.^2-2